# java how to call external unix command

Tags: java, bash, process

I would like to call a unix system command in java code, I write code like this:

`String cmd = "split -a -d -b 10M test.txt";`

`Process execProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

I hope when the external command is finished, I could continue to execute the following program. How to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
execProc.waitFor();
```

This should block until the command is finished. Also maybe you should consider using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it offers much more convenient API for handling processes.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = builder.start();
process.waitFor();
InputStream stream = process.getInputStream();
```